# Re-populate a ng-repeat table but keep it sorted as it was

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table I am filling with data from a webservice using `ng-repeat`. The user can sort the table by all columns, and every x seconds the app makes another poll to the webservice to get new data.

This  is my though process of how this app is going to work:

```
1st http.get [
    get data
    sort data  by time
]

interval [
    get new data
    only if the data has changes [
        display toast [
            if toast is clicked [
                take user to top of page
                sort the new data by time like 1st call ever
            ] else [
                do nothing
                keep same sorting order
                dont even refresh the data
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Currently I am pretty close *I think*, but something is going on when the new data is received. It is displaying it in the same order it is gotten from the webservice even though I call my *functional* sorting method. The same thing also occurs when I click on the toast. It is supposed to clear the amount of times the data has been updated (behind the scenes) and display the new data in order by time. I currently have this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2G9WyMPlVZV4J06xNXRo) I am working on. But here is the whole `$interval` area:

```
$interval(function() {
      $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4djr5').success(function(data) {

        if (angular.equals(data, $scope.tempdata)) { //this is going to be !angular.equals() but it is this for testing purposes
          console.log("here...");

          $scope.recentalerts = data; //recent alerts = the new data (that has new info in it)
          $scope.count++;
          toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": false,
            "debug": false,
            "newestOnTop": false,
            "progressBar": false,
            "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
            "preventDuplicates": true,
            "onclick": null,
            "showDuration": "300",
            "hideDuration": "1000",
            "timeOut": "2000",
            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
            "showEasing": "swing",
            "hideEasing": "linear",
            "showMethod": "fadeIn",
            "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
          };

          toastr.options.onclick = function() {

            $(function() {
              $('body').scrollTop(0);
            });
            $scope.order('-time');
            $scope.count = 0;
          };

          toastr["success"]("Click here to return to the top to view. +" + $scope.count, "New Alerts"); //display the toast

          $scope.tempdata = $scope.recentalerts; //the new data is now also the temp data to compare the next round to the new data

        } //end if

      });
}, 4000);
```

Sorry for all of the comments, I am just trying to keep my thoughts straight and this is confusing me. I'd like to elaborate more if need be, but I hope this will help you understand what i am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by saving the selected sort on a scope variable and then using that on your ng-repeat:

```
$scope.savedOrder = 'name';

$scope.order = function(predicate) {
  $scope.savedOrder = predicate;
  $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
  $scope.recentalerts = orderBy($scope.recentalerts, predicate, $scope.reverse);
};

<tr data-ng-repeat="alert in recentalerts | orderBy:savedOrder:reverse">
          <td>{{alert.name}}</td>
          <td>{{alert.time}}</td>
          <td>{{alert.ip}}</td>
          <td>{{alert.column}}</td>
          <td>{{alert.type}}</td>
        </tr>
```

**EDIT:**

Here's your plunkr with the proposed changes:

http://plnkr.co/edit/0qZLPBHhlgGZuS3Nm6Vi?p=preview

Comment: Oh that's a nice solution. One question though: When you click on the toast, why does it lag so long? I think there is an issue in there where `orderBy:savedOrder` is competing with the `onclick` of the toast. Inside the `onclick` of the toast I set `order('-time')` but then you're proposing that it follow saved order. Is that an issue, or is there a way to speed that up? It seems like it shouldn't be that slow.

Comment: Looks like it's because it's all happening inside of the interval. If you where to call $scope.$apply() right at the end of the onclick, the lag will be gone. Check out this revised plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0qZLPBHhlgGZuS3Nm6Vi?p=preview

Comment: Oh okay well that takes care of the lag thanks. Sorry to bug again, but any idea why the sorting now wouldn't work? Trying to debug. Seems the `$scope.apply()`interferes some how

Comment: So, for the DOM to be updated through two-way binding, angularjs uses watches on the scope that detect changes in the scope variables. These watches are triggered through the digest cycle, which in turn starts with a call to $apply(). Whenever you do something outside of angularjs context (e.g. inside of a setTimeout) you need to call $apply() manually. Now, you're using $interval(), which calls $apply() for you at the end of the function call, however, since your update to the model happens on the $http success, which is async, it happens after $apply() has already been called.

Comment: So you're saying after clicking on the toast the sorting through clicking the columns stop working?

Comment: @erp do you want to discuss this in the chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/77923/erp-and-jarz-chat?tab=general

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't know that about having to call if manually if outside of the context. But yeah prior to this, if you click the arrows @ the top it sorted the respective column either ascending or descending. now I am not sure what's going on. It appears to be random behavior. And sure in the chat!